# Year Make Model Google form that populates from a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, wordpress, google-forms

I need a webform with dependent drop downs (4 of them) thats populated from a google apps spreadsheet. Can someone point me in the right direction? I am a noob when it comes to google apps integration, so any help would be awesome. I'd like to make a google form that talks to the spreadsheet, and displays on a wordpress website. Thanks :)

Comment: Check this out with some [examples](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/miscellaneous/moving-item-from-one-listbox-to-another---google-apps-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this JQuery plugin to that - https://github.com/mikeymckay/google-spreadsheet-javascript

The below article explains how to use this plugin - 
http://www.digitalnotes.in/source-data-from-a-google-spreadsheet-into-a-webpage/